# ViewPager with animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement viewpager with the prevoius as next slide visible in a faded out manner as shown in https://dribbble.com/shots/2193499-Product-Card-Animation. Using zoom page transformation is not working properly.

Comment: can you share  your what you have tried, without code no one can help

Comment: http://developwear.com/blog/2014/05/09/carousel-view-pager-for-android-example/

Comment: https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The second one is a close match to what I want to achieve have to fade out the next and previous cards, though. Will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Screen slides are transitions between one entire screen to another and are common with UIs like slideshows.  **[ViewPagers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)** can animate screen slides automatically.

> ViewPagers have built-in swipe gestures to transition through pages,
>   and they display screen slide animations by default, so you don't need
>   to create any.

You can check below link for demo case

- **[ViewPager cards](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards)**